# Android AdMob example

Tags: android, admob

I downloaded example code of an Android project featuring AdMob ads from [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html).  In the picture, the ad says "AdMob Test Android Web Ad", but when I run the code, I sometimes see an actual ad and sometimes see nothing.  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that test mode is enabled on emulator. Seems like the code in the link does not have it's test mode enable.

Ads do not run immediately after launching the application. It would take a couple of seconds(up to 10secs, depending on your network speed) before being able to receive an advertisement from Admob.

Try something like this in your onCreate().

```
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a9876sf98dfg");        
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ad);        
    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(false);
    adView.loadAd(request);
```

EDIT (from the comments): Follow the instructions on  edumobile.org/android/android-development/admob-manager, but add the line "android:id="@+id/linearLayout" to the LinearLayout part of main.xml.

Comment: How do I put it in test mode?  I looked at the link provided in ThomasW's answer, but I couldn't get anything different to happen.  I'm noticing that either an ad gets loaded immediately, or there is still nothing even after several minutes.

Comment: I have edited the answer. You can try setting test mode enabling here. Similar to what I used.

Comment: On the `adView.setAdListener(this);` line, eclispe tells me "The method setAdListener(AdListener) in the type AdView is not applicable for the arguments (BannerXML)".  If I comment that line out, it runs, but I don't see any ads.

Comment: Alright, you can visit this website. http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/admob-manager/ I think it shows it better than my explanation here.

Comment: Thanks, I got that one working.  In case anyone else reads this later, I had to add the line "android:id="@+id/linearLayout" to the LinearLayout part of main.xml to get it to compile.